# Simple and safe way to wait for a Python Process to complete when using a Queue

Tags: python

I'm using the `Process` class to create and manage subprocesses, which may return non-trival quantities of data. The documentation states that `join()` is the correct way to wait for a `Process` to complete (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class).

However, when using `multiprocessing.Queue` this can cause a hang after joining the process, as described here: https://bugs.python.org/issue8426 and here https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming (not a bug).

These docs suggest removing `p.join()` - but surely this will remove the guarantee that all processes have completed, as `Queue.get()` only waits for a single item to become available?

How can I wait for completion of all `Process`es in this case, and ensure I'm collecting output from them all?

A simple example of the hang I'd like to deal with:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


def example_run(output):
    output.put([MyClass() for i in range(1000)])
    print("Bottom of example_run() - note hangs after this is printed")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    output = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=example_run, args=(output,)) for x in range(5)]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    print("Processes completed")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inelegant solution is to add

```
output_final = []
for i in range(5):  # we have 5 processes
    output_final.append(output.get())
```

before attempting to join any of the processes. This simply tries to get the appropriate number of outputs for the number of processes we've started.

Turns out a **much better, wider solution** is not to use `Process` at all; use `Pool` instead. This way the hassles of starting worker processes and collecting the results is handled for you:

```
import multiprocessing

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def example_run(someArbitraryInput):
    foo = [MyClass() for i in range(10000)]
    return foo

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)
    output = pool.map(example_run, range(5))
    pool.close();  pool.join()  # make sure the processes are complete and tidy
    print("Processes completed")
```

Answer (score 0):

> https://bugs.python.org/issue8426
>   This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that
>   all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed
>   before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that
>   processes which have put items on the queue will terminate.

In your example I just added `output.get()` before calling to `join()` and every thing worked fine. We put data in queue to be used some where, so just make sure that.

```
for p in processes:
    p.start()
print output.get()
for p in processes:
    p.join()

print("Processes completed")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @AlokThakur. I'm not 100% clear on how the `output.get()` line works - will this wait for *all* processes that have a reference to the queue to complete? The docs aren't clear on this. I need to guarantee I won't see a situation where one process takes much longer than the others and its results are missed (or it then still hangs on the `join()`.

Comment: @Giswok output.get() wait until there is some thing to get in queue, It won't wait for process. You can mention timeout in output.get(timeout). So if no process put any data in queue, this timeout would be used. You should read more on using queue effectively

Comment: issue 8426 suggests that if process put  large data in queue, then make sure to get it before joining the process.

Comment: Yes unfortunately the docs on Queue really aren't very clear. We still haven't found a way of directly waiting for all processes to complete, but this seems to work if done before the `join()`:   

`output_final = []`,  
`for i in range(nr_processes):
        output_final.append(output.get())`

It's rather inelegant though.

Comment: So is `output.get()` itself a blocking call and if all the info in the spawned process is pushed to the queue at the very end of the spawned processes lifetime could one get away with just using `output.get()` and not need to join?